# Using money-rails with mongoid: How to set currency per model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, mongoid, money-rails

I'm currently using:

money-rails v1.12
rails v6
mongoid v7

I would like to set the default currency to be used by each model instance.

I have set the field in my model like below

`field :price, type: Money, with_model_currency: :currency`

But when I try to create or fetch records I get this error

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFieldOption
message:
  Invalid option :with_model_currency provided for field :price.
```

How do I use the `with_model_currency` option in a rails mongoid application?
How else can I handle money in a rails mongoid application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use type: Money in a mongoid field, you're indicating that the field should be serialized / deserialized with that class in particular. RubyMoney includes methods for serializing to mongo. `with_model_currency` is not a valid option for the macro `field`.

You're confusing the method with the money-rails `monetize`, which DOES have an option named `with_model_currency`.

In one sentence: drop the `with_model_currency: :currency` option, it's not available on mongoid fields.

If you want to set a default currency, you will need to do so using `Money.default_currency = Money::Currency.new("CAD")`.

You might also want to write your own serializer (this was not tested):

```
class MoneySerializer

    class << self

        def mongoize(money)
            money.to_json
        end

        def demongoize(json_representation)
            money_options = JSON.parse json_representation
            Money.new(money_options['cents'], money_options['currency_iso']
        end

        def evolve(object)
            mongoize object
        end
    end
end



field :price, type: MoneySerializer
```

Relevant docs:

- https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails
- https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/6.1/tutorials/mongoid-documents/

Comment: I think it is clear now that `with_model_currency: :currency` is not available in mongoid.

However, if I am to use the other option of custom serialization, does this mean I can then update the `currency_iso` field per model instance. Essentially, I would like to see an example of how to create records with custom currency per model instance and reading the price attribute for each instance.

Comment: I will need a bit of time to have a working example in hands. Have you figured out this issue by yourself yet? In short, yes, you'll be able to set whatever currency_iso as you want, because you will be passing a Money object instance to Mongoid. That snippet I presented merely serializes / deserializes the object for you.